# How to make sure a user is still logged in using Java Web

Tags: java, session, authentication

I just want to ask how do I make sure  a user is still logged in. If he/she's not, then access to pages is not permissible. See, when logging in a page I use a filter to check if the user exists. I wonder if I could use filters to check if the user is still logged in? Only problem is, I tried but when I type the url directly on the address bar the page still shows, now with null values. How does one do this correctly in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a session variable, isLoggedIn=true, after the user logs in. In the filter, check if the session is null, or the logged in flag is false. If not, redirect to some page saying you must login to continue.

Comment: But good sir, if for example I have these pages:

JSP:
Login
Homepage
SomePage
Logout

Filter:
LoginInitial
CheckIfLoggedIn

and if I cast all the servlets with CheckIfLogged filter then if for example I don't log in but type in the url directly the url for a page inside login-logout(maybe SomePage) will the filter still work?

Comment: The filter is executed for every page you go to. Basically in the filter you only allow a logged out session to continue if they are trying to access the login page. Otherwise redirect. So if the user tries to go to /loggedInWelcome.jsp, your code will see the session doesn't exist and redirect to a pleaseLogin.jsp page

Comment: Sir how do I check the session in the filter? I tried using request.getSession in the filter but it wouldn't show. I tried request.getParameter then to see if I can take the session variable from them but even if I log in it can't get to the "loggedIn" variable, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: request.getSession() will give you the session. If it is null, then your user is certainly not logged in, this is their initial visit.

Comment: Good sir, finally made it work! What I did is:
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
I casted the ServletRequest taken in by the filter to an HttpServletRequest and it acquired the session variable! Is this practice acceptable? Or is there a Filter class which gets HttpServletRequest instead of ServletRequest?

Comment: Sounds good to me, that code lives in the filter I'm assuming- so its executed every time any request is made. Keep in mind, you might want to exclude certain images/css files from being filtered/redirected if they are used on your login page.

Comment: Finally I learned how to check if a user is logged in, the frameworks would be the next logical thing to learn, thanks Sir Greg! ^^

Answer (score 2):

What web framework are you using?

Yes, it is achievable using `filters/interceptors` in most scenarios, especially plain vanilla web applications. In your case, you most likely did not nullify/invalidate the invalid user, or have not redirected invalid users to another page (`login` page for example).

If you are using Struts, or Spring, i would highly recommend you looking in the direction of [Spring Security (Former ACEGI)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) or [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) because chances are although your home-made solution would appear workable, they are not spoof proof.

Comment: So it all leads back to frameworks... should I use filters over interceptors? Interceptors sound new to me. In regards to the Spring Security will learning AOP affect my web security by using advices or something?

Comment: Hi Kindling, interceptors and filters are used interchangeably. I.e. Interceptors are used to refer to filters in Struts 2.

Comment: Cool, I have experience in Struts 2. Should I use Struts 2 to develop a web app or Spring?

Comment: I personally would go for Struts2 over Spring Web.

Comment: Yey Struts2! I personally find it easier to use specially for MVC! Thanks Sir Chin Boon!